# table is mutating trigger cannot see it

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, insert

I have a table like so...

```
create table grades (id number, t1 number, t2 number, t3 number, mark number);
```

I want a trigger to calculate and update the table with the average mark for each row affected.

so I write a trigger like so...

```
create or replace trigger rades_trg 
after insert 
on grades
for each row
declare 
v_mark grades.mark%type;
begin
v_mark := (:new.t1 + :new.t2 + :new.t3) / 3;
update grades set mark = v_mark where id = :new.id;   
dbms_output.put_line(v_mark); 
end; 
/
```

then I enter a new record like so...

```
insert into grades (id, t1, t2, t3) values (5, 100, 100, 25);
```

but oracle tells me the  table may be mutating and the trigger cannot see it.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use a virtual column or a view, instead of storing redundant data?

Comment: Hopefully the `dbms_output.put_line` is just for debugging purpose. Otherwise you may get a ORA-20000: ORU-10027 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row triggers are generally not allowed to query or modify the table on which they're declared. To work around this I suggest that you make your trigger a BEFORE trigger so you can simply set `:new.mark` in your trigger:

```
create or replace trigger rades_trg 
  before insert on grades
  for each row
begin
  :new.mark := (:new.t1 + :new.t2 + :new.t3) / 3;
  dbms_output.put_line(:new.mark); 
end;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Even better no trigger.  Just column `MARK GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((t1+t2+t3)/3) VIRTUAL`.